# Installing rpm-package to systemd?

Tags: yum, rpm, systemd, rhel7

I am new to systemd, and trying to get an in-house app packaged as rpm, to install on systemd host (RHEL7).

The rpm tries to place the systemd .service-file: **myapp.service** 
into: **/etc/systemd/system**

But that generates an error, I dont understand:

```
file /etc/systemd from install of myapp-0:1-.i386 conflicts with file from package systemd-219-19.el7.x86_64
file /etc/systemd/system from install of myapp-0:1-.i386 conflicts with file from package systemd-219-19.el7.x86_64
```

and the installation aborts.

The install-related contents from .service-file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp
After=syslog.target network.target activemq.service
Requires=activemq.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
...
```

Any idea what the conflict might be?

Or how to troubleshoot?

**EDIT**: Adding the rpm-stuff from gradle build-file:

```
myappRpm {
    dependsOn build
    packageName 'myapp'
    arch I386
    os LINUX
    version buildVersion

    preInstall file('./deploy/rpm/preinstall')
    postInstall file('./deploy/rpm/postinstall')
    preUninstall file('./deploy/rpm/preuninstall')

    directory('/var/log/myapp', 755)
    directory('/opt/myapp/app', 755)
    directory('/opt/myapp/bin', 755)
    directory('/opt/myapp/config', 755)

    into '/opt/myapp'

    from('MyApp/build/libs/MyApp.war') {
        into '/opt/myapp/app/'
        fileMode 0755
    }

    from('deploy/systemd/myapp.sh') {
        into '/opt/myapp/bin/'
        fileMode 0755
    }

    from('deploy/systemd/myapp.env') {
        into '/opt/myapp/systemd/'
        fileMode 0755
    }

    from('deploy/systemd/myapp.service') {
        into '/etc/systemd/system/'
        fileMode 0755
    }

    doLast {
        file("$buildDir/distributions/myapp-${buildVersion}.i386.rpm").renameTo("$buildDir/distributions/myapp.rpm")
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in your .spec file, not your service. Please post that.

Comment: ehrm... what is a .spec file? --- we are building the rpm with gradle-rpm-plugin...

Comment: I added rpm-stuff from gradle build-script if that helps....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

each rpm specifies a list of files and directories that it installs. Two rpms cannot install the same files or directories. In your **spec file** (or whatever file you use to describe the rpm you build) you should **not** install the `/etc/systemd/` and `/etc/systemd/system/` directories. In a spec file; you should NOT use:

```
%files
/etc/systemd/
```

but

```
%files
/etc/systemd/system/*
```

(or specify each file separately)

**EDIT**

looking around for your gradle-plugin; You should use the `addParentDirs`option:

```
from('deploy/systemd/myapp.service') {
    // Will tell redline-rpm not to auto create directories, which
    // is sometimes necessary to avoid rpm directory conflicts
    addParentDirs = false
    into '/etc/systemd/system/'
    fileMode 0755
}
```

(look at the [full usage example on the nebula-gradle-plugin github page](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin) for more info)

Comment: Thanks, I added the gradle-script above. Looks ok to me, it's only placing the .service-file in /etc/systemd/system, what I can see. --- but, hmmm... but maybe it is the gradle-plugin that is somehow being "smart" and generates code to also create the parent-dirs, just in case --- then the error-msg would actually make some sense...

Comment: Thanks! I will try the addParentDirs option. Wasnt aware of that one.